# How to display multiselected values from a slicer in required order - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I Am trying to display the selected months from my slicer in a card visual.
I need this as my report title to signify which period is selected. Have sorted the month column and it works fine in any visual, but with the measure that I have created it doesn't work.
[image]

I want the months to be shown in the proper calendar format. My measure which concatenates all of them is

MultiSelect = IF(ISFILTERED(Principals[Month]), CONCATENATEX( ALLSELECTED(Principals[Month]),Principals[Month],","),"(All)")

Please help on how do I sort the months.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following expression

```
MultiSelect =
 CONCATENATEX ( VALUES ( Principals[Month] ), [Month], ", " )
```

### Output

[image]

## Edit:

`CONCATENATEX` would follow the sort order of the data. For example, my sample `Principals` table contains two columns. That means that `Month` column should be sorted by MonthSortOrder, as the image below shows.

[image]

### Table: Principals

| Month | MonthSortOrder |
| --- | --- |
| Jan | 1 |
| Feb | 2 |
| Mar | 3 |
| Apr | 4 |
| May | 5 |
| Jun | 6 |
| Jul | 7 |
| Aug | 8 |
| Sep | 9 |
| Oct | 10 |
| Nov | 11 |
| Dec | 12 |

### Output

Months are now ordered by their corresponding Month Number

[image]

Comment: I have achieved this but the problem is the months donot appear in proper order..

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect month order.